# getstream.io disable the fanout notification when a feed follows another

Tags: getstream-io

I have this scenario:

A user follows a feed and they receive all of that feed's current posts as new posts (via realtime notification.. likely caused by a fanout)

While its accurate that all that feed's items are new to the follower, I'd like to stop the notification from appearing..Is it possible to disable the fanout notification when a feed follows another?

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have a way to suppress realtime notifications upon follow. The only way I think you could accomplish this would be for User A to follow User B without copying any old items, but then User A would only see new activities going forward.

I'll mention this to the team as a feature request.